# Update of List of Tables in Microsoft Word page numbers only (Table of Figures, Table of Tables)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft

I am only able to update the whole list of tables in microsoft word but there is no option to update only the number of pages like the list of figures... does anyone have an idea about how to update only the pages of the list of Tables?

Comment: See if something here helps: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/two-ways-to-generate-a-list-of-tables-in-a-word-document/

Comment: @BlindSpots I am sorry but I couldn't find something for my answer there but thanks for your aid!

Answer (score 0):

### A Table of Tables and a Table of Figures, in Word, are the same thing - just with different labels.

They both use the [TOC field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c) and the TOF style. *From my webpage*, here are the fields for a Table of Contents, a Table of Figures, and a Table of Tables:

> [image: screenshot]

They should both display the same dialog asking if you want to update the entire table or simply page numbers. *Some changes in either your Table of Tables or in the source material may trigger simply an update to the entire table rather than simply page numbers.* The same thing happens with a Table of Contents.

Here is a link to [my writing on Tables of Figures/Tables](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures).

Comment: Unfortunately, for me updating only the pages appears in the case of table of content and list of figures but not in the list of Tables. I am using Ms word 2016. I don't know why that option does not appear for the list of tables, there is only the option of updating the whole table... is there a way to update only the pages?

Comment: The same thing can happen with a regular Table of Contents or the List of Figures as well. It has to do with the changes made in your document. If there are enough changes, it just updates the table as a whole. I do not know what those changes are. How/why is this causing you problems?

Comment: Yes it worked regarding the update! Thank you! I wish to know how to see the list of cross references in word? I mean how to see the things that are cross referenced in one table or in one list? Since I couldn't find it

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question. How do I ask a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What should I do when someone answers my question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I did here it is https://superuser.com/questions/1755060/list-of-cross-reference

Comment: If your original question has been answered, please mark the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers